# MySQL query returning an error

Tags: php, mysql, database

This returns a MySQL error:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['inputName2'];
$email = $_POST['inputEmail2'];
$instruments = $_POST['instruments'];
$city = $_POST['inputCity'];
$country = $_POST['inputCountry'];
$distance = $_POST['distance'];

// ^^ These all echo properly ^^

// CONNECT TO DB
$dbhost = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";
$dbuser = "xxx";
$dbpass = "xxx";

$con = mysqli_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpass", "$dbname");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "INSERT INTO depfinder (name, email, instrument1, instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5, city, country, max_distance) VALUES ($name, $email, $instruments[0], $instruments[1], $instruments[2], $instruments[3], $instruments[4], $city, $country, $max_distance)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con)); // script fails here

if (!$result)
{
    echo "There was a problem with the signup process. Please try again later.";    
}

else
{
    echo "Success";
}
}
?>
```

N.B. I'm not sure whether it's relevant, but the user may not choose five instruments so some `$instrument[]` array values may be empty.

Bonus question: is my script secure enough or is there more I could do?

Comment: What is the output of die(mysqli_error)?

Comment: $insturments is only loading one item, not an array, since you can only pass one variable by that name.

Comment: Actually I think you have an extra column / column missing - you have 10 in your field list but 11 in the data

Comment: @bhttoan thanks, that's fixed, but the problem persists. The output of `die(mysqli_error)` is just `mysqli_error`.

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use could you expand on that please? Could be the source of my problem.

Comment: $instruments is a flat value, not an array value.

Comment: Does any of your input data contain quotes etc? That answers your "bonus" question as no this is not secure....

Comment: `die(mysqli_error)` should be `die(mysqli_error($con))`

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use How do you know it's a fla value? He didn't post the HTML. If he uses `name"instruments[]"` then it will be an array.

Comment: I've never passed data that way, thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around the string values in the query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO depfinder 
            (name, email, instrument1, instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5, city, country, max_distance) 
         VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$instruments[0]', '$instruments[1]', '$instruments[2]', 
                 '$instruments[3]', '$instruments[4]', 
                 '$city', '$country', $distance)";
```

To answer your bonus question, your script is not secure at all, it is susceptible to SQL injection, and will also get a syntax error if any of the values contain apostrophes. You should use a prepared query with parameters rather than string substitution. Or if you use substitution, you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to protect against injection and syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Is `mysqli_real_escape_string` used when defining variables?

Comment: Column count in OP code is wrong - might be worth changing for anyone coming across this later

Comment: @Sebastian `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is used when you define the string that's going to be inserted to the table... in your specific case, for example: `$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['inputName2']);` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the lack of single quotes around the variables in your query seems to have been the initial issue. So that can be considered a quick fix.

But I went ahead and refactored your code to streamline it a bit as well as provide some basic validation.

Additions of note include using a `$post_array` to roll through your `$_POST` values and do basic value checking with `isset` & `!empty`. Just a side note, but in your original script—and in this cleanup—you are setting a `$distance` string but then you are not actually using that in this code. Does it show up later? Realted but what is `$max_distance`? Could you have mixed up `$distance` with `$max_distance`? Fair typo, but just something I noticed.

Also, another option to get away from the single quotes is to use `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` which I have set here as `mysqli_free_result` & `mysqli_close` to neatly end the MySQL process.

```
// Set a '$_POST' array and roll through each value.
$post_array = array('inputName2', 'inputEmail2', 'instruments', 'inputCity', 'inputCountry', 'distance');
foreach ($post_array as $post_key => $post_value) {
  $$post_value = isset($_POST[$post_value]) && !empty($_POST[$post_value]) ? $_POST[$post_value] : null;
}

// CONNECT TO DB
$dbhost = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";
$dbuser = "xxx";
$dbpass = "xxx";

// Set the connection or die returning an error.
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

// Set the query.
$query = "INSERT INTO depfinder (name, email, instrument1, instrument2, instrument3, instrument4, instrument5, city, country, max_distance)"
        . " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        ;

// Bind the params.
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'ssssssssss', $inputName2, $inputEmail2, $instruments[0], $instruments[1], $instruments[2], $instruments[3], $instruments[4], $city, $country, $max_distance);

// Run the query.
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

// Check if the result is returned & echo a message based on that.
if (!$result) {
    echo "There was a problem with the signup process. Please try again later.";    
}
else {
    echo "Success";
}

// Free the result set.
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Close the connection.
mysqli_close($con);
```